# swagger jersey + jaxrs query param not working

Tags: java, swagger, query-string, swagger-ui

I am using swagger(1.2) for documenting my jersey + jaxrs (2.1) api. I used swagger-ui for displaying my api. For http GET request i have a query parameter as @QueryParam("token") in api endpoint. Swagger is displaying the field for this query parameter but when i click on "Try it out!" button everytime i received null value for it.

I also annotated @QueryParam("token") with @ApiParam but it didn't work. Can anybody please explain what i doing wrong in it. Do query param really works in swagger?

Comment: Which version of swagger-ui do you use? Have you checked in the web console to see that the parameter is actually being sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there was a bug introduced into the master branch of swagger ui.  It was fixed today:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/729

Can you give that a shot?